# Python demonstration for drawing trees

Tags: python-3.x

I'm setting up a demo of Edmond's Algorithm in Python 3. The algorithm itself is working, but I am having difficulty rendering the graphs in a simple way. Since this is meant for students without previous graphics experience to tinker with, I don't want to scare them off by making the drawing parts too complicated.

What is the simplest way to draw text and lines in Python, either directly on the screen or to an image file? The only necessary functions are "put a string (S) at coordinates (x, y)" and "put a line between (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)".

Comment: It seems you are asking us to find some kind of tool for your students to use, unfortunately that is considered off topic for StackOverflow, please refer to the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page and if you think your question is in fact on topic you may consider rewording the question to focus on a more specific programming issue.

Comment: (Otherwise I'd recommend looking at `tkinter.Canvas` and it's `create_line` and `create_text` methods.)